# Facebook Webhook for subscribing to a page (conversations) doesn't send a notification

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, facebook-webhooks

I've been trying to setup a subscription to a page I own on Facebook using an App I've been using for many years (and this used to work for subscriptions to another Page).

Webhooks are setup, and a subscription has been created for 'conversations' to post back to a url on our server. When I test this through the webhooks page I can see the request come through on the server.

The only step that seemed to be missing was subscribing the page to the app itself.

However, I have now done this by issuing a POST request through the Graph Explorer directly to [page_id]/subscribed_apps. This returns true. When doing this however it requires a Page Access Token and gives me the Facebook authorization popup with a message saying:

"Submit for Login Review - Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook."

I've worked out it means the 'manage_pages' permission.

If I click "OK" it goes through (presumably because the user I am authorizing as is a page admin?).

When I do a GET request to the same endpoint ([page_id]/subscribed_apps) I can see my App listed.

However, when a conversation on the page is updated (comment or new post) I don't receive a notification on the server.

Could this be because the permission isn't approved by Facebook, despite the fact that it shows as a subscribed App? I definitely didn't have to go through this before as the same App is live listening on notifications from another page without that permission granted, but I'm questioning whether something has since changed in the API.

Unfortunately this project goes live tomorrow so I don't have time to go through the Facebook review process...

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I just attempted to subscribe to the description and/or mission fields on the page and edited these as the page owner and the notification came through instantly via the same webhooks subscription... which makes this even more confusing as it only seems to be failing for "conversations" eg: new posts/comments.

Comment: "Urgent" doesn't make people hop to your question any faster. If anything it draws negative attention.

Comment: If this is a really important problem you need solved *immediately* you should use coaching services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: Sorry, I've amended the title. I don't post here often as you can tell... :(

Comment: No problem being new here. Questions like this could take a few hours for someone who knows Facebook's API well enough to address, so if it is urgent consider your options.

Comment: You need `read_page_mailboxes` permission as well, that is the basis for getting access to the page’s messages/conversations to begin with.

Comment: Actually I got it working just now by subscribing to the "feed" instead of "conversations" and that reports all page activity. Thanks for the help.